# Class' instance as argument python

Tags: python, class, methods, arguments

I am searching for a class method which decides which arguments will be given when an instance of the class is given as an argument.

I have this:

```
class Answers_Matrix(list):

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if (type(value) is int):
            if (0 <= value <= 255):
                list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
            else:
                print "Invalid value size."
        else:
            print "Invalid value type. Value must be an integer."

    def __repr__(self):
        # a function I made which returns a matrix in a string format
        return _matrix_to_string(self)

    # **EDIT:**
    # here I want a __asargument__ or something alike, so when an instance 
    # of this class is given as an argument I can decide what and how it 
    # will be given.

    # Example:
    # def __asargument__(self):
    #     array = (ctypes.c_ubyte*len(self))(*self)
    #     return array
```

Is there something alike in python which I can use?

Comment: Perhaps if you were to include a concrete use for such a method...

Comment: Can not understand you question. Please describe more clearly or better an example.

Comment: Class, or object of that class?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible. There is no way to say that when you call

```
foo(Answers_Matrix())
```

`foo` will actually receive some other thing derived from `Answers_Matrix()`. This is for good reason, as it would be incredibly confusing and difficult to implement. Particularly, it's very likely that you'd want to use `self` as an argument to something in the hypothetical `__asargument__` method, and that'd lead to either infinite recursion or extremely confusing context-sensitive semantics for when `__asargument__` is or isn't called.

If you want object A to be replaced with object B whenever you try to use it for anything, don't have object A in the first place. Just use object B.